# WoWLAN not working

Tags: wifi, wake-on-lan

WoLAN works fine but WoWLAN isn't on ubuntu 22.04

```
$iw list | grep -A 4 "WoWLAN support"
     * wake up on disconnect
     * wake up on magic packet
     * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
       maximum packet offset 0 bytes

$iw phy0 wowlan show
WoWLAN is enabled:
 * wake up on disconnect
 * wake up on magic packet

$sudo ethtool enp2s0 
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Link detected: no
```

I use Termux to wake up using `wol <PC_MAC_ADDR>`